# cross validation after lasso

Tags: cross-validation, lasso

I used cross validation to select lambda. Then I performed lasso and get non zero coefficients (features). Shall I perform cross validation for these non zero coefficients as a kind of validation?

Comment: I am not clear about your question. What do you mean by "features selected by LASSO as a kind of validation for selected features". Also, I am not clear about "using different thresholds"? and also " input matrix for LASSO". I suggest you to ask your question in a more formal way.

Comment: I agree, your question is not clear at all. Perhaps you could provide a small working example?

Comment: No, CV is enough. Unless you want to go back and do a different CV (ie 10-fold, etc). This would be a better way to "validate" your results if you feel uneasy.

Answer (score 1):

(Just guessing what you are actually asking)

> Shall I perform cross validation for these non zero coefficients as a kind of validation

The final model (with the LASSO-determined coefficients) needs to have its own validation with a set of completely unknown cases in order to get a good estimate of its performance.

That is, if you do a cross validation for this final model validation step, you need to need to wrap another "outer" cross validation around all calculations that lead to the LASSO-model (including the "inner" cross validation you used for tuning of $\lambda$).

This is known and discussed here under the name of [double cross validation or nested cross validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=double+nested+cross+validation) - it is a resampling version of the splitting into training-tuning-final model validation (aka test) method.